# Does Play Store counts pre-installed apps?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app in Play Store. This same app is going to be pre-installed in some phones. The app is signed with the same key and application package is same. In this case, does Play Store count this install and show it in Developer Console statistics?

(When the Play Store has a newer version of the app, I could update the pre-installed app to the newer version through Play Store. And this is reflected in statistics as an upgrade. This is expected behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes all things are correct. Play store manage all apps by its pakagename so if it already available and you update your app on play store then it is counted by play store.and one more thing is play store automatically inform your all previous user to update is available for this app.play store also display upgrade pin your console for as reminder when you update your app.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But updating the app through Play Store is clear for me. What I'm interested in is pre-installed app count. I want to know whether they are counted and shown in Play Store statistics. Because these apps are not installed via Play Store. They are pre-loaded in the ROM.

Comment: it counted if only if it downloaded play store and not from device to device or any other way. if it downloaded once from play store it countable. and after update it just replaced previous app with updated app and there are no changes in consol statistics...

Comment: What if application is pre-installed (which will not be counted because it is not downloaded from play store) and a user updates it, it will effect the total installs stats of developers console or not?

Comment: @HassanJamil If pre-installed apk is not downloaded from play store and its display update  option in play store then it will not effect in the total installs stats of developers console.

Comment: @JayeshKhasatiya Thank you so much for your replying. Can you please provide any official reference if exists? I have searched but didn't find anything.

Comment: @HassanJamil : Here I have added one more thing If you have downloaded app from other site and if you online then its automatically counted in Playstore and if you did that offline then when you goes online count increased automatically. I hope I have cleared all thing. So our device play store app do that  thing background.